# Why does black not move Queen here?

Tags: learning, strategy, stockfish

in this board, after Nf5 as indicated, why does stockfish suggest the best move is king-knight e7? Surely it would be better to save the Q to h7 towards the check-mate on h2 (white knight blocks the white bishop, so Q safe here). Any ideas? Am I missing something obvious? Thanks.

[image: Kf5 | King-Ke7]

Comment: Yes, you are missing something half-obvious:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nf5 ...Qh7, Nd6+ (discovered attack) wins the queen. Note that any other attempts to save the queen fails:

- Nb4 or Nce7 or Nge7 or Nf6 with the idea to attack the white queen fail because Nxg7+ is check
- Qg6 has the same problem as Qh7, i.e. loses the queen after Nd6+
- Qxe5 Rae1 (or Rfe1) pins the queen. Unpinning the queen with Nge7 (or Nce7) and an attack on the white queen does not help since after Rxe5 the knight on e7 is pinned and cannot capture the white queen.

Comment: Agreed. Everything lost for Black. The computer suggests Nge7 because it at least develops a piece. The best decision in a hopeless position.

Comment: Yes and interestingly it prefers this to Qxe5 which loses the queen to a rook (not to a knight). Probably this is because after Qxe5 the open e file helps white's attack.

Answer (score 3):

After Nf5 ...Qh7??, Nd6+ wins the queen.